# React with Django in production

Tags: django, reactjs, apache, architecture

I am planning to deploy an application which is built in react frontend, and calls a python backend. What I am planning is to deploy react on a linux box on a node.js server and python on django behind Apache.

Can someone would suggest if this would be right architecture from production grade perspective?
If application is expected to get 1000 requests per hour, then will this architecture work? or I should replace or add components or layers?

Answer (score 1):

Generally, you run both servers on different ports, and then point apache to django server for /api/ calls (or whatever URLs need to go to django api), and then the rest of the regular requests you point at node.js serving your javascript frontend application.
1000 requests per hour seems like nothing - depending of course on the work of the backend server - but in general any webserver should handle that no problem.

Apache has following settings for this:

```
ProxyPass        "/api"  "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api"
ProxyPassReverse "/api"  "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api"
```

You can read more in documentation here: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/reverse_proxy.html

Comment: Thank. But I heard that Django and node are not suitable for production (load and security wise). And what if I say 1000 requests per minute? I am open to choose other technologies if you have any suggestions

Comment: not sure where you heard this, both are widely used for big websites.

Comment: Thanks.. Let me search some documentation around my doubt. It would be really helpful if you have any reference towards production usage